# Proper syntax in active record for where clause that contains an OR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, where-clause

Can anyone tell me the proper syntax for the following?

```
User.where(id_a: 2 OR id_b: 2).count
```

I'm trying to find the total number of users with either an `id_a` of 2 an or `id_b` of 2, but everything I try returns some error.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `where`, which suggests to me you need a `Rails` or `ActiveSupport` tag.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: It's actually from the `active_record` library.

Comment: Rails isn't magic, it cannot introduce new syntaxes to Ruby. Hashes have nothing to do with logic, you cannot embed "or" conditions in them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
User.where("id_a = ? OR id_b = ?", 2, 2).count
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to repeat the same parameter 2 times and if the `?` makes you dizzy :), you can use the elegant "placeholder conditions" syntax described [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#array-conditions) (see section 2.2.1) as follows:

```
User.where("id_a = :user_id OR id_b = :user_id", user_id: 2).count
```